# 'make_interp_spline' line dropping between two points

Tags: python, matplotlib, interpolation

I am plotting some points and to make the plot smoother I'm using 'make_interp_spline'. The problem is that I get a falling line between the first two points. The other points are ok, and they have the same distance. Is there something I can do about it?

Ps: I just have the data from 10 and 30.

**My code:**

```
import matplotlib
import pylab as pl
from pylab import *
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import make_interp_spline

x1, y1 = np.loadtxt('Grafico_I_D_Fe.txt', dtype=float, delimiter=',', unpack=True)

B_spline_coeff1 = make_interp_spline(x1, y1)
X1_Final = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 500)
Y1_Final = B_spline_coeff1(X1_Final)

pl.plot(X1_Final, Y1_Final, color='r', label=r'Iron ($2 \times 10^7$)')
pl.scatter(x1, y1, marker='*', color='r')
```

**Data:**

```
10, 3.187170532786709e-15
30, 1.031832270812154e-13
50, 3.444779276423242e-13
70, 6.316369610195546e-14
```

**Plot:**
[image: Plot]

Comment: Could you please remove `from pylab import *`? `ìmoprt *` puts a lot of functions into the local namespace, which can lead to many surprises. Also, `pylab` is deprecated.  Since 2011, you should `from matplotlib import pyplot as plt` instead of `import pylab as pl`.

Comment: Maybe the spline gets through negative values, which disappear in a log scale plot?  In general, an interpolating spline can be very wiggly, especially when more points are interpolated.  You might consider using a different type of spline.  See e.g. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.PchipInterpolator.html

Comment: Hi @JohanC I removed 'from matplotlib import pyplot as plt' and also changed 'from matplotlib import pyplot as plt' to 'from matplotlib import pyplot as plt', but nothing changed.

Comment: @JohanC there are no points going through negative values. There are only these four points from data.

Comment: Your data points aren't negative, but the interpolating curve could be.  That is an annoying property of simple interpolation.  Your use  of `pylab` isn't the cause of the problem, it is only a cause of a lot of confusion. The cause of your problem is `make_interp_spline` instead of e.g. `PchipInterpolator` or, better yet, an approximating curve instead of an interpolating one.

Comment: @JohanC I have changed the line 'B_spline_coeff1 = make_interp_spline(x1, y1)' to 'B_spline_coeff1 = pchip_interpolate(x1, y1)' and I'm getting this error: TypeError: pchip_interpolate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'.

Comment: My linked pointed to `from scipy.interpolate import PchipInterpolator` and `B_spline_coeff1 = PchipInterpolator(x1, y1)`.  `pchip_interpolate` is a related, but a bit different function. As the docs explain, you'd call it as `Y1_Final = pchip_interpolate(x1, y1, X1_final)`

Comment: It worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interpolation functions often have the unintuitive property of wiggling a lot. In your case, the interpolated curve goes below zero, although the data points don't.

Many other interpolation or approximation functions exist, each having their own benefits and drawbacks for specific situations. `PchipInterpolator` is one such function, that tries to stay inside the range of the data points (but has a less nice second derivative).

The code below uses [`PchipInterpolator`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.PchipInterpolator.html), but also takes the log of the input y-values, and reverses that operation via `exp` on the result. Without taking the log, the wobbly second derivative is more visible.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import PchipInterpolator

x1 = [10, 30, 50, 70]
y1 = [3.187170532786709e-15, 1.031832270812154e-13, 3.444779276423242e-13, 6.316369610195546e-14]

B_spline_coeff1 = PchipInterpolator(x1, np.log(y1))
X1_Final = np.linspace(9, 71, 500)
Y1_Final = np.exp(B_spline_coeff1(X1_Final))

plt.plot(X1_Final, Y1_Final, color='r', label=r'Iron ($2 \times 10^7$)')
plt.scatter(x1, y1, marker='*', color='r')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.show()
```

[image: PchipInterpolator]

PS: It seems that for these specific data points, the original `make_interp_spline` works even better than `PchipInterpolator` when using the log conversion.  Often this won't be the case, and you might need to consider other interpolation or approximation functions.

```py
B_spline_coeff1 = make_interp_spline(x1, np.log(y1))
X1_Final = np.linspace(9, 71, 500)
Y1_Final = np.exp(B_spline_coeff1(X1_Final))

plt.plot(X1_Final, Y1_Final, color='r', label=r'Iron ($2 \times 10^7$)')
plt.scatter(x1, y1, marker='*', color='r')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.show()
```

[image: make_interp_spline and taking log]